# Can't set background image using mpdf

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

The following is what my html looks like it contains two pages to print using mpdf.
I am trying to set images for the two pages namely Front.jpg and Background.jpg. But mpdf is not loading those images.

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        @page :first {
            background-image: url("/home/mehul/www/portal.hsua.com.au/public_html/templates/wordings/Front.jpg");

            background-position: top center;

        }
        @page {
            background-image: url(/home/mehul/www/portal.hsua.com.au/public_html/templates/wordings/Background.jpg) 50% 0 repeat;
        }
        div.front {
            page : first;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="front">

<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.9cm">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.9cm">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.9cm">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.9cm">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="margin-left: 75px; color: red; font-size: xx-large">{{@version}}</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>
        <style type="text/css">@page { size: 21.03cm 29.7cm; margin-right: 2.54cm; margin-top: 2.53cm; margin-bottom: 0.88cm }
        p { margin-bottom: 0.25cm; direction: ltr; color: #000000; line-height: 120%; orphans: 2; widows: 2 }
        p.western { font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
        p.cjk { font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
        p.ctl { font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
        a:link { so-language: zxx }
        </style>
    </h1>

    <p align="center">
        <style type="text/css">@page { size: 21.03cm 29.7cm; margin-right: 2.54cm; margin-top: 2.52cm; margin-bottom: 2.54cm }
        p { margin-bottom: 0.25cm; direction: ltr; color: #000000; line-height: 120%; orphans: 2; widows: 2 }
        p.western { font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
        p.cjk { font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
        p.ctl { font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
        a:link { so-language: zxx }
        </style>
    </p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-left: 0.42cm; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><font size="5" style="font-size: 18pt"><i>About </i></font></font><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><font size="5" style="font-size: 18pt"><b>High Street Underwriting Agency</b></font></font></p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.02cm">&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-left: 0.49cm; margin-right: 0.95cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 112%"><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><i>High Street Underwriting Agency Pty Limited (High Street) is a member of the Underwriting Agencies Council (UAC). High Street is an authorised Coverholder of Certain Underwriters at Lloyds and is licenced to wholesale insurance in Australia.</i></font></p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.38cm">&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-left: 0.49cm; margin-right: 0.35cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 112%"><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><i>In effecting this Contract of Insurance, any cover is accepted by High Street acting under an authority given by the subscribing Underwriters and High Street is acting as Agent of the Insurers and not the Agent of you, the Insured.</i></font></p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.35cm">&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.35cm">&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.38cm">&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-left: 0.42cm; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><font size="5" style="font-size: 18pt"><i>About </i></font></font><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><font size="5" style="font-size: 18pt"><b>Certain Underwriters at</b></font></font><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><font size="5" style="font-size: 18pt"><i> </i></font></font><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><font size="5" style="font-size: 18pt"><b>Lloyd&rsquo;s</b></font></font></p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.02cm">&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="western" style="margin-left: 0.49cm; margin-right: 0.32cm; margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 113%"><font face="Arial, sans-serif"><i>Security is provided by Certain Underwriters at Lloyd&rsquo;s. Lloyd&#39;s currently enjoys an A+ rating from Standard &amp; Poor&#39;s, AA- from Fitch and A from A.M. Best. These ratings are independent opinions of Lloyd&rsquo;s financial strength and ability to meet its ongoing insurance policy and contract obligations.</i></font></p>


    <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm; line-height: 0.53cm"><img align="left" border="0" height="43" hspace="12" name="Image3"

    <p align="right" class="western" style="margin-right: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: which mpdf version are you using?

Comment: As I saw, I think the problem is in image path: `/home/mehul/www/portal.hsua.com.au/public_html/templates/wordings/Front.jpg`
maybe correct path is
`/templates/wordings/Front.jpg`
try it

Comment: I will implement that tomorrow.